# Conditionally Combine PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a clean way to combine 2 PHP Arrays conditionally?
I get the following JSON-Response from both arrays separately:

1st Array:

```
[
      {
        "field": {
          "id": 20,
          "name": "Erfolge",
          "field-id": "erfolge",
          "type": "textarea"
        }
      },
      {
        "field": {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "Sprachen",
          "field-id": "sprachen",
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
]
```

2nd Array:

```
    [
  {
    "field": {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Erfolge",
      "field-id": "erfolge",
      "type": "textarea"
    },
    "value": "new entry"
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Trikotnummer",
      "field-id": "trikotnummer",
      "type": "number"
    },
    "value": "test"
  },
  {
    "field": {
      "id": 29,
      "name": "Sprachen",
      "field-id": "sprachen",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "value": "Text"
  }
]
```

I want the following target output:

```
    [
      {
        "field": {
          "id": 20,
          "name": "Erfolge",
          "field-id": "erfolge",
          "type": "textarea"
        },
        value: "new entry"
      },
      {
        "field": {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "Sprachen",
          "field-id": "sprachen",
          "type": "text"
        },
        value: "Text"
      }
]
```

That means it must only add the values if the field exists in the 1st array.
My current solution gives me all the fields without the correct mapping:

```
$fieldData = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $fieldData[]['fields'] = $field->getArrayCopy();
    }

    // Get Values
    $values = $user->getProfileFieldValue();

    $fieldValue = array();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $fieldValue[] = $value->getArrayCopy();
    }

    $result = array_merge($fieldData, $fieldValue);
```

Should I use the function array_walk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expensive way to do it, it searches the second array looking for the element matching the ID from the first array.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($first as $e1) {
    $id = $e1['field']['id'];
    foreach ($secondArray as $e2) {
        if ($e2['field']['id'] == $id) {
            $e1['value'] = $e2['value'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $e1;
}
```

If the second array is very large, you can optimize it by first creating an associative array whose key are the IDs from the second array and values are the values.

Comment: you missed a `1` here: `$id = $e1['field']['id'];`

Comment: Although your solution is expensive, i will use this iterations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php

```
$res = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function($a, $b){
  return $a['field']['id'] - $b['field']['id'];
});
```

Comment: Great answer, OP only needs to swap the $arr1 and  $arr2 to get the desired result ( `array_uintersect($arr2, $arr1, ...` )

Comment: @Danijel reconsidered my previous comment. For intersection between only 2 arrays the order of arguments is unimportant, but once you get to 3 or more arrays you need to bear in mind that your basis of comparison must always be first.

Comment: @Sammitch: How can I also add the value to the new array? Thanks.